# Remove the Asterisk from required

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any way that we can remove the required asterisk from required?

```
<lightning-input class="searchInputCmp" name="enter-search" label={inputLabel} onchange={handleTextChange} onblur={handleBlur} type="search" value={selectedItem} required={isRequired} ></lightning-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show the label, it will have the asterisk. You can hide the label entirely with `variant="label-hidden"`. You could use an alternative type of component, such as using the basic [SLDS blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/).